# how to define field in Word before uploading to DocuSIgn

Tags: templates, ms-word, docusignapi

There are some fields in a template that need to be filled before uploading to DOcuSign. The sender wants to fill out these fields before uploading, but I also need to have them picked up by the Connect web app.

I have tried defining textboxes in the Word doc, but when the template is applied, I can see the field value under the Textbox when I look at it in recipient preview mode DocuSign. I need to be able to get the value of the field, but don't know how to do it if it's already filled in before it's uploaded.  It only seems to work if the sender has to fill it out after sending the envelope.

Answer (score 0):

getting data out of a signed envelope can be done only if the data was shared with DocuSign. There are no APIs to getting meta-data out of the document if these were not set as custom field, tags or some other DocuSign object that includes the data.
You could write code that gets these from the Word document yourself using Word APIs or some other technique and then adding them to the envelope using customer fields.